# Is there a wbo-like SAT-Solver for Python?

Tags: python, computer-science, solver

Is there a Python-Module / Program, that solves a SAT Problem? Probably a weighted Boolean one. (To be specific, something like [wbo](http://sat.inesc-id.pt/wbo/index.html))

Or if not are there maybe bindings, or an API to use one of those solvers.

I don't think i could programm one myself in the time i have right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to solve SAT problems I would suggest using MiniSat (http://minisat.se), Glucose (https://www.lri.fr/~simon/?page=glucose) or Picosat (http://fmv.jku.at/picosat) and there are others. In the case of pseudo-boolean optimization I know of MiniSat+ (http://minisat.se/MiniSat+.html) and Gurobi (http://www.gurobi.com). I think all of them are free, except Gurobi, which offers trial and academic licences).

All of them offer a command line interface with input and output files that are easily generated/read from within Python. Moreover, Gurobi features a full Python shell.

Comment: In addition, since you work with Python, have a look to PuLP  (http://pythonhosted.org/PuLP), an LP modeler written in python.

Answer (score 4):

Picosat has bindings for python ([pycosat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycosat))

Comment: It's super simple to start, and has examples on the web (e.g. sudoku). Very natural clauses (positive or negative ints). I don't see the optimization functionality (weighted soft constraints), but it's right there, available after `pip install pycosat`.